# JS Set color picker value

Tags: javascript, colors, set, picker

I want change color picker value.
Like this
$('#headcolor').val('#e2e2e2');

## headcolor is

`<input id="headcolor" type="color" />`

I need help :( Sorry about my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have shown changing color of text using color picker

```
<html>
   <body>
      <input id="headcolor" type="color" onchange="func()"/>
      <p id="temp">Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>
      <script>
         function func() {
             document.getElementById("temp").style.color = document.getElementById("headcolor").value;
         }
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3uex0d4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just JavaScript like this: `document.getElementById("headcolor").value="#e2e2e2";`

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_color_value

Hope it helps!